# Jquery children() opacity animation

Tags: jquery, css, opacity

My problem: I'm fairly new to Jquery I'm trying to get append the class `'.visible'` to the '.content' div once an animation has completed.

Each image div contains an image as a cover that grows to fill the whole area.

Essentially each content div has additional text content that I only want to appear once a user has clicked on the parent element and then fade out on the second click as the parent element returns to the original size.

I'm doing it this way rather than trying to just set an opacity value as I want to keep it cross-browser compatible.

My attempted solution: I've been playing around with `.children().addClass('visible')` but have had no luck. I am fairly sure I'm making a rookie mistake, but after searching Stackoverflow and other sites I've not been able to find an answer that deals with this situation (though that might be through incorrect searching on my part).

The Jquery code so far:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".image").bind('click', function() {

        var that = $(this),
        offsets = that.position(),
        top = offsets.top,
        left = offsets.left,
        clone = that.clone(),
        parent = that.parent(),
        width = parent.width(),
        height = parent.height();

        clone.addClass('clone').appendTo(parent).css({
            'top': top,
            'left': left
        }).animate({
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0,
            'width': width,
            'height': height,
        }, 1000).click(function(){
            $(this).fadeOut().siblings().animate({
                'opacity': 1
            }, 1000);
        }).siblings().animate({
            'opacity': 0.1
        }, 1000);
    });
 });
```

Hopefully I've posted enough information, but I'm happy to share the html and css as well if that helps.

The relevant CSS classes are:

```
  .content { 
      filter:alpha(opacity=0); 
      -moz-opacity:0; 
      -khtml-opacity:0; 
      opacity: 0; 
  }

  .visible { 
      filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
      -moz-opacity:1; 
      -khtml-opacity:1; 
      opacity: 1;
  }

  .wrap { 
      height: 725px; 
      width: 974px; 
      margin: 0 auto; 
      vertical-align: top; 
      position:  relative;
 }

 .image { 
      height: 233px; 
      width: 233px; 
      display:inline-block; 
      vertical-align: top;   
      margin: 0 11px 11px 0; 
      background-size: cover; 
      border: 1px solid #000000;
 }
```

Apologies if I have been imprecise with any of my problem reporting and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could i see your HTML please. :)

Comment: Absolutely: http://gunnarroxen.com/hubsite/hubsite/index.html

Comment: I really like your website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a simple example of how this can be done, but first, let's talk about coding.

When you code, try to make small manageable -- and readable -- chunks, and structure it so that it makes sense, and for the *love of god* comment on what you're doing or you're gonna come back scratching your head asking "what does this do again?".
If you do this, it'll be much easier to debug when something goes wrong.

Now, let's talk about some of the minor issues.
When using JQuery, it is recommended to use [`$(document).ready(function(){...});`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) as your entrance point.

[`.bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) has been deprecated since long long ago, even its successor [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated for a while now, you should be using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), but we only really need to use it if the content has been added dynamically to the DOM after `.ready`.

Phew, ok, now that that's been taken care of, here's my simple example to get you going in the right direction.

---

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wz46F/) | Code

Javascript

```
var scale_increase = 1.5,
image_fade = 500,
txt_fade = 250;

$(document).ready(function(){
    //Attach click event handler
    $(".img-container").click(function(){
        var self = $(this);

        var img = $("img", this),
            txt = $(".img-text", this);

        //Make sure we aren't animating, otherwise the image resizing will not match
        if(img.is(":animated") || txt.is(":animated")) return;

        if(self.hasClass("img-displaying")){
            //Revert back to default state
            self.removeClass("img-displaying");

            //Hide the text
            txt.animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, txt_fade, function(){
                //After the text has been hidden, make the image smaller
                img.animate({
                    width: parseInt(img.prop("width"))/scale_increase,
                    height: parseInt(img.prop("height"))/scale_increase
                }, image_fade);
            });
        }else{
            //Make picture larger and show the text
            self.addClass("img-displaying");

            //Make the image bigger
            img.animate({
                width: parseInt(img.prop("width"))*scale_increase,
                height: parseInt(img.prop("height"))*scale_increase
            }, image_fade, function(){
                //After it's grown, show the text
                txt.animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, txt_fade);
            });
        }
    });
 });
```

HTML

```
<div class='img-container'>
    <img src="http://images.wisegeek.com/young-calico-cat.jpg" width="200" height="156" />
    <div class='img-text'> This is a cute kitty I want to cuddle with! :)</div>
</div>

<div class='img-container'>
    <img src="http://images.wisegeek.com/young-kittens.jpg" width="200" height="148" />
    <div class='img-text'> Oh dear, they're SO adorable!</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.img-text{
    text-align: left;
    font-style: italic;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

### References (in order of appearance)

- [`$(document).ready(function(){...});`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)
- [`.click(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [`.is(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)
- [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)
- [`.hasClass(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)
- [`.removeClass(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)
- [`.animate(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
- [`.prop(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)
- [`.addClass(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Comment: Thank you - that is a really helpful answer and gives me lots to look at, and learn from. Thanks for taking the time to correct my bad habits!

Comment: @Slerbal Here to help! It's really important to correct bad coding habits before they "settle in". You can always check out the [good 'ol wiki page about coding practices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_Coding_Practices) for some more pointers

Comment: Thanks - I will check out those links. Your referenced code has given me lots to work with.